# How to create scrollable dropdown list in Svelte?

Tags: select, drop-down-menu, html-select, svelte

I want to create a dropdown with scrollable list items. I used `overflow-y: scroll;` in CSS but not worked as I expected. Please check the sample svelte code written below.

```
<script>
    let names = ['Name1','Name2','Name3','Name4','Name5',
        'Name6','Name7','Name8','Name9','Name10',
        'Name11','Name12','Name13','Name14','Name15',
        'Name16','Name17','Name18','Name19','Name20',];
    
    let selected;
</script>

<select bind:value={selected}>
        {#each names as name}
            <option value={name}>
                {name}
            </option>
        {/each}
</select>
```

[Svelte REPL Example](https://svelte.dev/repl/7f222a9c6f5842968f9002f1b2b8e1ce?version=3.52.0)

How can I achieve this in Svelte?

I need to display the dropdown lists as in the picture

[image: Expected result]

**EDIT**
I used the size attribute for the `<select></select>` tag but the list items are not selectable and the dropdown height is getting broken. I want to display the scrollable dropdown list items when I click on the dropdown field.

Answer (score 1):

Set a size `<select ... size="8">`

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried using the size attribute. But 8 items in the list are shown at a time. I need to create the scrollable options list only when I click on the select menu. Any idea on the same?

Comment: @AnanduSuresh don't ask follow up stuff in the comments. Either modify your question and notify of the change or start a new question